# Use user input to search for a certain node in an xml using java

Tags: java, xml

I have this xml code

I want to be able to have a scanner or some other object that asks for user input, then use that input to match a certain node and display that node and the rest under it.

For example, I want to have an option to search for either name, address, email, phone, or group.  If i choose name, i want to be able to input the name "tim" then use that input to find the node and display it along with the sibling nodes, but only for that specific contact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<contactInfo>
    <contact>
        <name>tim</name>
        <primary_address>1111 virginia road</primary_address>
        <secondary_address>N/A</secondary_address>
        <primary_email>asdf@gmail.com</primary_email>
        <backup_email1>N/A</backup_email1>
        <backup_email2>N/A</backup_email2>
        <primary_phone>703-111-1111</primary_phone>
        <backup_phone1>N/A</backup_phone1>
        <backup_phone2>N/A</backup_phone2>
        <group1>family</group1>
        <group2>friends</group2>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name>john</name>
        <primary_address>1111 pike road</primary_address>
        <secondary_address>N/A</secondary_address>
        <primary_email>john@gmail.com</primary_email>
        <backup_email1>N/A</backup_email1>
        <backup_email2>N/A</backup_email2>
        <primary_phone>222-222-2222</primary_phone>
        <backup_phone1>N/A</backup_phone1>
        <backup_phone2>N/A</backup_phone2>
        <group1>friends</group1>
        <group2>N/A</group2>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <name>Tim Calara</name>
        <primary_address>1234 Wallaby Way</primary_address>
        <secondary_address>N/A</secondary_address>
        <primary_email>tim@gmail.com</primary_email>
        <backup_email1>N/A</backup_email1>
        <backup_email2>N/A</backup_email2>
        <primary_phone>111-123-4567</primary_phone>
        <backup_phone1>N/A</backup_phone1>
        <backup_phone2>N/A</backup_phone2>
        <group1>family</group1>
        <group2>friends</group2>
    </contact>
   </contactInfo>
```

This is the search part of my code, let me know if you need my whole code (the whole this is lengthy).

```
public void search() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException
{
    System.out.println("\nSearch for Contact");
    int choice = searchMenu ( );

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: 
        try 
        {

            File file = new File("/Users/T/Eclipse Workspace/contactInfo/nData.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDocument = dBuilder.parse(file);
            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            System.out.println("Please enter Contact name: ");
            String input = kbd.nextLine();

            String expression = "/contactInfo/contact[name() = "input"]";
            System.out.println(expression);
            Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
            if(null != node) {
               NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
                for (int i = 0;null!=nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
                    if(nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() + " : " + nod.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
                }
            }


        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    //case 2:

    //case 3: email ( ); break;
    //case 4: phone ( ); break;
    //case 5: break;            
    //case 6: exit (); break;
        }       
}
```

Comment: Have you at least attempted anything?

Comment: yes but all my attempts result in null everything or it prints out all the contacts and not just the one I need

Comment: Fair enough, if you display your code some people might be able to point out why your results are `null`.

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: Well, your update made most of my answer below irrelevant, but it does show what's wrong with your XPATH query. Look at the way mine is built (matches the `name` element and not the `name()` function, wraps strings between `'` characters...), adapt yours, it should fix your issue. Also, I'm fairly sure your code doesn't compile, the way you declare the `expression` variable is highly suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example, will find the first element that contains a `name` child with a content of `tim`, and print the content of its `name` and `primary_address` elements:

```
Document doc   = getDocument();
XPath    xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodeList;

nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//name[.='tim']/..", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node contact = nodeList.item(i);
    System.out.println("Name: " + ((Node)xpath.evaluate("name", contact, XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent());
    System.out.println("Address: " + ((Node)xpath.evaluate("primary_address", contact, XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent());
}
```

This is probably not the cleanest way of doing it, but it does the job. You can wrap most of it in helper methods - note how similar the two `println` statements are, they're just crying out for factorisation.

[EDIT] updated the example as requested in the comments

Comment: This actually really helps, thank you.  Now I just need to create a scanner object for a user to input a name and then have the scanner object name in the place of 'tim'.

Comment: You already have most of the logic in your original code, your only problem is with the XPATH query itself.If you can afford it, take the time to read up on XPATH - it's surprisingly easy to get fluent with, and it'll make your life *much* easier if you have to spend a lot of time working with XML.

Comment: could you maybe give me the next part that would display the address, because i'm trying and failing at figuring out how to get the siblings.  If you don't want to, that's fine, but it would really help

Comment: for some reason i keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It works fine for me with the same XML sample. If I had to take a guess, I'd say your document is `null`, the structure of your XML document is not the same as the one you pasted or you're attempting to retrieve a non-existing contact. Look at your `NullPointerException`'s stack trace, it'll tell you which line your error occurs and where to start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried JAXB?

*"Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) allows Java developers to map Java classes to XML representations."*

Then you could just iterate over objects.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding

Comment: I'm learning XML for the first time so I don't know what JAXB is.  If i had a little sample of code, i could maybe understand it.

Comment: @TimCalara: Happily, there is a very nice JAXB tutorial included as part of the official Java SE tutorials package published by Oracle and available on their website (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/).  As you're learning Java, a nice bit of advice from Joshua Bloch (whose book would be highly valuable to you; Effective Java, 2nd Ed.) is "always look to the libraries for a solution to a problem before beginning to code your own."

Comment: Exactly, why attempt to re-invent the wheel when someone has already spent the time to create and test something that does the job for you? :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can map your XML representation to Java classes with JAXB: In the given XML the `ContactInfo` element contains a list of `contact` child elements. If you represent `ContactInfo` and `Conatct` as Java objects, `ContactInfo` will contain a list of `Contact` instances.Below is a sample code to achieve this:

Create `Contact` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Contact{
private String name;
private String primaryAddress;
//other properties
// getters and setters
}
```

And here is the `ContactInfo` class, which contains a list of `Contact` objects representing the contact elements of your XML file:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ContactInfo {
private List<Contact> contactList;

public List<Contact> getContactList() {
    return contactList;
}

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ContactList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Contact")
    public void setCustomerList(List<Contact> contactList) {
        this.contactList =contactList;
    }
}
```

Now, by using JAXB you can read your xml file as follows:

```
File file = new File("Path to your xml file");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ContactInfo.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
ContactInfo contactInfo = (ContactInfo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

And you can also create your xml from `ContactInfo` as below:

```
//create your "ContactInfo" object with a list of "Contact"s
ContactInfo contactInfo=new ContactInfo();
List<Contact> list=new ArrayList<>();
//add contacts to the list and add the list to ContactInfo

File file = new File("path to save your XML file");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ContactInfo.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(contactInfo, file);
```

I suggest you to read this : [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) to get a good idea about the API.